# Javascript memory card game last card not flipping

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a memory game that has a demo here.

https://kuochye.github.io/memorygame/

I have a issue with the last card not flipping over and can't figure out why.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".flip-container").forEach(card => card.classList.add("clicked"));
setTimeout(function () {
document.querySelectorAll(".flip-container").forEach(card => 
card.classList.remove("clicked"));
}, 30000);
```

^ This was what I did to show the cards for 30 secs before it flips down. But somehow the last card is not showing.

```
  // Build single card
 var buildCardNode = function (index, value, isRevealed, width, height) {
var flipContainer = document.createElement("li");
var flipper = document.createElement("div");
var front = document.createElement("a");
var back = document.createElement("a");

flipContainer.index = index;
flipContainer.style.width = width;
flipContainer.style.height = height;
flipContainer.classList.add("flip-container");
if (isRevealed) {
  flipContainer.classList.add("clicked");
}

flipper.classList.add("flipper");
front.classList.add("front");
front.setAttribute("href", "#");
back.classList.add("back");
back.classList.add("card-" + value);
back.setAttribute("href", "#");

flipper.appendChild(front);
flipper.appendChild(back);
flipContainer.appendChild(flipper);

flipContainer.addEventListener('click', handleFlipCard);

  document.querySelectorAll(".flip-container").forEach(card => card.classList.add("clicked"));
setTimeout(function () {
document.querySelectorAll(".flip-container").forEach(card => 
card.classList.remove("clicked"));
}, 30000);

return flipContainer;

 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is looking for every card that has already been added and flipping it. That would be fine, but you're doing it before adding each card to the document. So for each card added it finds every card added previously and flips it.

You want to be doing one of two things instead:

a. Flip all cards after they have been added to the document (by moving that first piece of code out of buildCardNode function to where it is called from).

b. Flip each card directly before it is added to the document (instead of using document.querySelectorAll.forEach, you use flipContainer.classList.add/remove).

Comment: That totally makes sense now! Option b was simple and perfect! Thank you so much.